# How to fix jog button of samsung U28D590D display

Tags: display

I have a Samsung U28D590D display, and that little joystick/button in the back is broken and do not work correctly.

Is there a way to access the OSD configurations through a software or a easy way to fix this?

Comment: The [user manual](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201510/20151030173012594/BN46-00481B-Eng.pdf) calls "that little joystick/button" the "JOG button" (capitalization in source).

Mine is broken too :(

Comment: If you're going to crack it open, a service manual is a good idea. The jog button looks *suspiciously* like a PS/2 style joystick

Comment: The jog button may only be unseated. Try to put the display face down and carefully push until getting a click.

Comment: Laying my display face down and moving the button around worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Admittedly, I've not tested it on your specific model but *IF* your monitor supports DDI/DDC and you want to set basic things like brightness and colour, [ClickMonitorDDC](http://clickmonitorddc.bplaced.net/) works. Its portable so its pretty easy to test

It *only* works on my dell, not my other generic monitor, but it gives you at least the basic brightness/contrast and RGB settings if it works.

[image]

Comment: Late to the party, but I've had a "broken" jog button on my U28D590D for years. I downloaded the ClickMonitorDDC software and can confirm it works for this model. The real kicker is that I hit the "Reset Monitor" option, and lo and behold, the jog button is functioning perfectly now!

Comment: Curious and super cool.

Answer (score 2):

I sprayed WD-40 generously inside the joystick cavity and tried as much as I could with the long spray nozzle to get behind the joystick. I then moved the joystick in circular motion and pressed it while still wet. Works as good as new now.

Comment: I actually opend the monitor a bit. It was really easy for my model c27jg52. Just a few screws on the bottom where the jog sits and then spray and pray.

Answer (score 1):

I sprayed some contact cleaner into the JOG switch, wiggled it around a bit, and now it works as good as new.

Answer (score -1):

I also had the problem with the JOG button and the fix is super easy although you have to open the monitor case.

Go around the edges of the casing and use small hard plastic tools to get a grip and free the Monitor from the casing, then just readjust the JOG button. Test before putting everything back together and done! No screws and you can finally use the button again and use the setting or whatever.